# Making a string property ObjectId in MongoDB with C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I just started with MongoDB. I am using it with C# drivers. Currently C# class looks like this:

```
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public List<string> filters { get; set; }
```

With this class I am able to save and fetch the records in MongoDB.

**What I want**:- Instead of creating a separate property to hold `ID` (in my case its `Id` property), I want to make `userId` property as the ObjectId.

**Please note**, I will be supplying the userId which will be a `unique string value`. Is it possible to achieve this with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

just put [BsonId] on userId prop and delete Id property